# MPI_Allreduce : very strange false results

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a huge code with a very strange MPI bug. MPI parallelization is trivial with just the computation of a mean value somewhere in the code that can be isolated as :

```
// Declaration
std::vector<double> local;
std::vector<double> global;
unsigned int size;
/* ... huge computations here ... */
size = 10000; // approximately
local.resize(size);
global.resize(size);
local.shrink_to_fit();
global.shrink_to_fit();
/* ... some operations to fill in the local vector ... */
MPI_Allreduce(local.data(), global.data(), int(size), 
              MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
/* ... some final operations here ... */
```

But if I plot the values of `global`, there is about `10` erroneous values (over `10000`) distributed randomly in the vector (but always between the `~1000th` and `~2000th` value) which :

- are not the same for all MPI tasks (~80% of the tasks have the same erroneous values, but the remaning ~20% have different ones)
- are not the same for 2 different runs (not reproducible)

I have tested the program with `valgrind` on `1` processor (just removing `MPI_Init`, `MPI_Allreduce` and `MPI_Finalize`) and there is no memory leaks or problem of any kind (at least this is what `valgrind` tells me).

The normal number of tasks for the parallel version is `1024`, and the program is in `C++11` compiled with `g++4.8.1`.

`Valgrind` was my last hope, and I have absolutely no idea of what is happening. Any idea or suggestion is welcome !

Note : the problem may not be in the code itself (MPI config, hardware, etc...), so any idea on what to test is welcome.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. `MPI_ALLREDUCE` normally just returns one value (the sum of local here). You're trying to store it in an array it appears.

Comment: @WesleyBland - if you give the reduction operation an array of inputs, it operates on each element independently and generates a same-sized array of reductions.  It took me a while to figure that out initially because all the examples (including in books) generally just use scalars.

Comment: This is really weird.  Something is happening that shouldn't, so my first suggestion is to independently change a number of things that shouldn't matter and see if we can narrow it down.  If you take out the computation and just fill the vectors with dummy data, do you still see the problem?  After that, how about if you just use 1d arrays instead of vectors?  What's the smallest number of processors you start seeing this on? Does adjusting the collective algorithms (in OpenMPI, --mca coll ...) change anything?  If you can make a short reproducer I'm happy to look...

Comment: Gah, You're right @JonathanDursi. Disregard all comments from me here then.

Comment: @JonathanDursi Problem solved (see the explanation below if you are interested in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information, after 2 days of research the problem is solved now. `MPI_Allreduce` does not crash if there is a buffer size mismatch but produces strange behaviours instead. I've discovered that by replacing them by `MPI_Reduce` + `MPI_Bcast` (and the `MPI_Reduce` crashed due a buffer size mismatch). The bug cannot be found using only the information provided in the question : the key was on the line :

```
size = 10000; // approximately
```

and the word `approximately` because in my real code, this size relies on a lot of calculation and numerical integrations of differential equations. But this code is using an hybrid parallelization `MPI+std::thread`. And some parts of the integrations relies on `std::thread` and the last digits of the integrations relies on the non-predictive order of operations. And the final `size` depends a lot on that. So, as each MPI task was executing its threads in different orders, the `size` was slightly different for two or three MPI tasks ... causing an undefined behaviour (but with no crash) in `MPI_Allreduce`.

Comment: Instead of Valgrind, you should have used [MUST](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/zentrale_einrichtungen/zih/forschung/projekte/must) (shameless plug - MUST is being developed here).